# Attributing data from multiple polygons to larger polygon by proportion contained using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.3, intersection

Using ArcMap 10.3.1.

I have searched for an answer, but have only found reference to merging polygons which does not answer my question.

I have two shapefiles, one representing postcode regions and the other representing larger regions [image: Example]

Each postcode polygon has a value (total number of survey participants). I would like to 'assign' the data from the postcode polygons to the regional polygons; however, some postcode polygons intersect more than one regional polygon. I'd like to allocate to whichever polygon it is most contained within, and then sum the 'number of participants for the region.

I have tried 'Spatial Join' and 'Intersect' but these have not worked out.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would use:

1. the Intersect tool to assign to each part of each postcode the region to which it belongs
2. ArcPy to determine which region you are going to assign each "disputed/shared" postcode to.
3. the Summary Statistics tool to calculate for final statistics